# Cannot decrypt encrypted file by AWS SDK with Minio server

Tags: c#, encryption, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, minio

I use :

- minio server to store files
- nginx as reverse proxy to be able to use https with minio server
- .NET AWSSDK.S3 to communicate with Minio server through nginx

Since server side encryption does not work with minio server, I tried to use the client side encryption help with AWS. But decryption of the file does not work with minio server.

When I use the same code with AWS server account, encryption / decryption work well.

It seems that file loses its metadata when it is created in minio server.

When I try to get file I have an exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException' occurred in AWSSDK.Core.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to decrypt data for object file-stream-27e52c5f-05d1-4296-

Here is my code

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string filePath = @"c:/tempPrivateKey.txt";
        string privateKey = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        RSA rsaAlgorithm = RSA.Create();
        rsaAlgorithm.FromXmlString(privateKey);
        EncryptionMaterials encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(rsaAlgorithm);
        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey);

        AmazonS3CryptoConfiguration cryptoConfig = new AmazonS3CryptoConfiguration
        {
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1,
            StorageMode = CryptoStorageMode.ObjectMetadata,
            ServiceURL = EndPointNginx,
            UseHttp = false,
            ForcePathStyle = true
        };

        _amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(credentials, cryptoConfig, encryptionMaterials);

        string bucketName = "bucket-" + Guid.NewGuid();

        string fileStreamKey = "file-stream-" + Guid.NewGuid();

        Stream fileStream = CreateRandomFileOnStream();

        CreateBucket(bucketName);

        AddFileToBucket(fileStreamKey, fileStream, bucketName);

        Stream fileStreamToRead = GetFile(fileStreamKey, bucketName);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStreamToRead))
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }

        DeleteFile(fileStreamKey, bucketName);

        DeleteBucket(bucketName);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void AddFileToBucket(string fileKey, Stream fileStream, string bucketName)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine();
        Console.Out.WriteLine($"adding file {fileKey} to bucket {bucketName}.");

        var objectToPut = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = fileKey,
            InputStream = fileStream
        };

        _amazonS3Client.PutObject(objectToPut);

        if (fileStream.CanRead)
            fileStream.Dispose();
        Console.Out.WriteLine("file added");
    }

    private static Stream GetFile(string fileKey, string bucketName)
    {
        // This line throw an exception.
        GetObjectResponse response = _amazonS3Client.GetObject(new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = bucketName, Key = fileKey });
        return response.ResponseStream;
    }
```

At worst I will encrypt / decrypt the file manually but I would like to be sure if there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening have you tested our Minio server recently we do support SSE-C now.